# C++ std::string initialization better performance (assembly)

Tags: c++, optimization

I was playing with www.godbolt.org to check what code generates better assembly code, and I can't understand why this two different approaches generate different results (in assembly commands).

The first approach is to declare a string, and then later set a value:

```
#include <string>
int foo() {
    std::string a;
    a = "abcdef";
    return a.size();
}
```

Which, in my gcc 7.4 (`-O3`) outputs:

```
.LC0:
        .string "abcdef"
foo():
        push    rbp
        mov     r8d, 6
        mov     ecx, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     edx, edx
        push    rbx
        xor     esi, esi
        sub     rsp, 40
        lea     rbx, [rsp+16]
        mov     rdi, rsp
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+16], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rbx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], 0
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long)
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        mov     rbp, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        cmp     rdi, rbx
        je      .L1
        call    operator delete(void*)
.L1:
        add     rsp, 40
        mov     eax, ebp
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
        mov     rbp, rax
        jmp     .L3
foo() [clone .cold]:
.L3:
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        cmp     rdi, rbx
        je      .L4
        call    operator delete(void*)
.L4:
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    _Unwind_Resume
```

So, I imagined that if I initialize the string in the  declaration, the output assembly would be shorter:

```
int bar() {
    std::string a {"abcdef"};
    return a.size();
}
```

And indeed it is:

```
bar():
        mov     eax, 6
        ret
```

Why this huge difference? What prevents gcc to optimize the first version similar to the second?

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/rpb5Z3)

Comment: did you turn on optimizations? what compiler flags did you use?

Comment: No, I am trying it only in the godbolt.org compiler.

Comment: You can still set flags in godbolt. And comparing non-optimized code is pointless.

Comment: Comparing resulting assembly code without optimizations turned on is completely irrelevant. Add the -O3 flag and try again. The assembly should be identical.

Comment: "only in godbolt.org" ? There is no "only". I am not aware of something godbolt cannot do ;). Comparing the output of the compiler without turning on optmization is moot when you care about performance

Comment: Looking at un-optimized assembly isn't very helpful.  There is a lot of code, debug and normal, that can make two operations look the same without optimizations but have vastly different characteristics when optimized.

Comment: fwiw here is the examples with optimization: https://godbolt.org/z/nCF66S surprisingly only the second example is optimized to simply return 6.

Comment: The "_better assembly code_" is the one you use in the field and which work.

Comment: Unoptimized code is slow and sometimes does weird and unnecessary things : news at 11.  Always, always, *always* enable the optimizer when investigating performance related issues.

Comment: Also, more or less opcodes is not necessarily slower or faster. You have to be careful when comparing assembly codes. A best option to measure performance is measuring time intervals.

Comment: @JesperJuhl "_Always, always, always_" :-D I see what you did there

Comment: you'd get my upvote if you include the optimized output, because now I am really curious what is the "problem" with the first version

Comment: Also: you cannot just count "lines of assembly" and use that as a measure of performance. Code using more statements can easily be faster than code using fewer statements. 1 ASM instruction is not equal to 1 unit of time. Some ASM instructions take hundreds of clock cycles, some take just one or two. Counting instructions/statements is just *wrong* and doesn't tell you *anything*

Comment: @Ted Do tell, because I don't 

Comment: With the optimizations, everything is different, and this interesting behaviour doesn't occurs.
The first version becomes only the return, and the second version is much bigger than that.

Comment: `<rant>`When I was _actually_ writing code in assembly to get things done, it was hand optimization that counted. Every operation had clock cycles clearly stated (thank you Rodnay Zaks) so you could actually sum them up and do the performance math on paper (interrupts excluded). This does not apply today. Your compiler and your CPU will get the better of you everyday!`</rant>`

Comment: I allowed myself to edit, simply rollback if you dont like it

Comment: This way, there is nothing interesting about this matter =/

Comment: @JesperJuhl Turn on `-O3` :-)

Comment: why nothing interesting? I dont see why `foo` is not simply `return 6` similar to `bar`

Comment: Very weird the behavior of the first example with -O3. I'm also interested...

Comment: Indeed @formerlyknownas_463035818. The question is still interesting. Thank you for the upgrade.

Comment: I think this additional behavior is due to default ctor call.

Comment: I guess the problem is caused by GCC decision **not to inline** `_M_replace` member function (defined [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc#L424)). I can't understand why inlining is not applied here. I even was not able to force GCC to inline this function, using inline-control compiler flags (such as increasing `-finline-limit`). `_M_replace` is called from `assign`, which is invoked by `operator=` for `const char*` arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a guess:

`operator=` has a strong exception guarantee; which means:

> If an exception is thrown for any reason, this function has no effect (strong exception guarantee).
>   (since C++11)
>
> [(source)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D)

So while the constructor can leave the object in any condition it likes, `operator=` needs to make sure that the object is the same as before; I suspect that's why the call to operator delete is there (to clean up potentially allocated memory).